# How do I query the number of objects on an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, active-record-query

I have a `Profile` and that `has_many :ratings`.

What I want to find are the number of `Profile` objects that have more than 1 rating record associated with it.

I tried the following to no avail:

```
> Profile.includes(:ratings).where('ratings.count > 0').count
   (38.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles" WHERE (ratings.count > 0)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ratings"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles" WHERE (ratings.count > 0)
                                               ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles" WHERE (ratings.count > 0)
```

And

```
> Profile.where('ratings.count > 1').count
   (28.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles" WHERE (ratings.count > 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ratings"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles" WHERE (ratings.count > 1)
                                               ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles" WHERE (ratings.count > 1)
```

**Note** That my `ratings` model does not include a column called `count`. What I am trying to do is `count` the number of `ratings` objects associated with each `profile` record and return the number of `Profile` records that have more than `1` rating associated object.

How do I achieve that with ActiveRecord?

**Edit 1**

Trying two more queries per user793789's suggestions:

```
> Profile.includes(:ratings).where('ratings.count > 1').references(:ratings).count
   (55.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "profiles"."id") FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE (ratings.count > 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 1: ...N "ratings"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE (ratings.co...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "profiles"."id") FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE (ratings.count > 1)

> Profile.joins(:ratings).where('ratings.count > 1').count
   (40.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles" INNER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE (ratings.count > 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 1: ...N "ratings"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE (ratings.co...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles" INNER JOIN "ratings" ON "ratings"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE (ratings.count > 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Profile.includes(:ratings).where('ratings.count > 0').references(:ratings).count
```

**OP's Edit 1**

After much backing and forthing, we finally settled on this:

```
Profile.joins(:ratings).group('profiles.id').having('count(ratings.id) > 0').length
```

But I feel like there must be a more simple way to do this.

Comment: or 
Profile.joins(:ratings).where('ratings.count > 0').count

Comment: Nope...neither of those work for me. Did they work for you?

Comment: `Profile has_many :ratings`. Refresh the question, I posted the error logs for both suggestions.

Comment: I think postgres is mistaking ratings.count as a function. probably you can try to rename count column in your table

Comment: Oh...I don't have a `count` column in my ratings table. I was referring to the rails method `.count`. What I want to do is retrieve the number of ratings on each `profile` object and then only return the number of `profiles` that have more than 1 associated `rating` object. I hope that's more clear.

Comment: Profile.joins(: ratings).having('count(ratings.id) > 1').count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127417/discussion-between-user793789-and-marcamillion).